# Mocking overloaded method

Tags: unit-testing, scala, mocking, scala-2.10

I am using scalamock to mock a class that contains some overloaded methods but I am getting some errors.

For example:

```
val out = mock[PrintStream]

(out.print _).expects("cmd \r\n")
```

Raises the following error:

```
[error] [...]/src/test/scala/chili.scala:19: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
[error] both method print in class PrintStream of type (x$1: String)Unit
[error] and  method print in class PrintStream of type (x$1: Array[Char])Unit
```

But if I try to use:

```
(out.print(_: String)).expects("cmd \r\n")
```

I also get an error:

```
[info] [...]/src/test/scala/chili.scala:19: Unable to resolve overloaded method print
[info]       (out.print(_: String)).expects("cmd \r\n")
[info]                 ^
[error] [...]/src/test/scala/chili.scala:19: value expects is not a member of String => Unit
[error]       (out.print(_: String)).expects("cmd \r\n")
```

Is there any way to do this in scala? Maybe using another library?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe the compiler errors you are seeing have to do with the fact that scalamock can not properly mock the `PrintStream` class.  If look at the scalamock [scaladocs](http://scalamock.org/api/index.html#org.scalamock.package) you will see the statement:

```
At present, ScalaMock can only mock traits, Java interfaces, and non-final 
classes that define a default constructor
```

As the `PrintStream` class is neither an interface nor does it have default constructor, my guess is that scalamock can not properly mock it and the errors you are seeing are a side effect of that.  If you changed your code to use a `OutputStream` instead (which is an interface and thus meets scalamock's restrictions), you could do your overloaded method mocking like this:

```
val mockStream = mock[OutputStream]      
(mockStream.write(_:Int)) expects(1)
(mockStream.write(_:Array[Byte])) expects(Array[Byte](1,2,3))
```

Personally, I prefer Mockito used within [Specs2](http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/) as it does not have these kinds of restrictions.  An example of a class using `PrintWriter` and then a test spec for that class using mocking with Mockito is as follows:

```
import java.io.PrintStream
import java.io.File
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification
import org.specs2.mock.Mockito

class MockitoExample extends Specification with Mockito{
  val mockPrinter = mock[PrintStream]
  val myPrinter = new MyPrintingClass{
    override val printer = mockPrinter
  }

  "A request to print and attay of strings" should{
    "call println on the PrintStream for each string supplied" in {
      myPrinter print Array("foo", "bar")
      there was one(mockPrinter).println("foo")
      there was one(mockPrinter).println("bar")
    }
  }
}

class MyPrintingClass{
  val printer = new PrintStream(new File("foo.txt"))

  def print(strings:Array[String]) = strings foreach (printer.println(_))
}
```

Now this is a very trivial example, using only post-test verifications with no pre-test stubbings (because `println` has a `Unit` return type), but at least you can see that Mockito does not suffer from the same restrictions as scalamock.  You can read more about using Mockito with Specs2 [here](http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.Matchers.html#Mock+expectations).